# How to extend jQuery UI widget _create method?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm having a LOT of pain trying to do something very simple : extend a jQuery UI widget, namely the autocomplete one.

Here is what I am doing :

```
(function($) {
    $.widget("my.autocomplete", $.extend({}, $.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {     
        _create: function() {
            $.Widget.prototype._create.apply(this, arguments);
        },
    }));
})(jQuery);
```

Of course, it doesn't work even though it is exactly what the official jQuery UI documentation recommends :

http://jqueryui.com/docs/Developer_Guide

Can someone help on this ? I'm confused and have been stuck for many hours now...

Thanks by advance,

Eric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer after many hours of confusion :

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._create.apply(this, arguments);
```

Instead of :

```
$.Widget.prototype._create.apply(this, arguments);
```

Working like a charm...

Comment: Thank you. I was trying the exact same method as you.